# labels with tabular

Tags: tables, labels

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Critical temperature for different Type I superconductors is given in Table \ref{Tab:Tcr}:
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    material  & T [K]\\
    \hline
    Sn                     & 3,7 \\
    Pb                     & 7,2 \\
    Al                     & 1,2\\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Tab:Tcr}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output is [image]

The table reference is missing in the text. How to display the table reference?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't `\label` a `tabular`, because a `tabular` does not receive an intrinsic ordering scheme (aka a number) that can be referenced. But if you place the `tabular` inside of a `table`, you can `\label` that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Critical temperature for different Type I superconductors is given in Table~\ref{Tab:Tcr}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{My Table}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    material  & T [K]\\
    \hline
    Sn                     & 3,7 \\
    Pb                     & 7,2 \\
    Al                     & 1,2\\
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Tab:Tcr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I will add an version that defies my earlier assertion.  With the `caption` package, the `\captionof` macro is provided to emulate a `table` without the use of the floating `table` environment.  And `\captionof` can take a label.  So, technically, you still are not `\label`ing the `tabular`, but only the `\captionof`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
Critical temperature for different Type I superconductors is given in Table~\ref{Tab:Tcr}
\begin{center}
  \captionof{table}{My Table\label{Tab:Tcr}}
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    material  & T [K]\\
    \hline
    Sn                     & 3,7 \\
    Pb                     & 7,2 \\
    Al                     & 1,2\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I may, loading `caption` would be useful here.

Comment: @Bernard Would that be because it provides `\captionof` or did you have another reason in mind?  I modified to make use of the `\captionof` approach.

Comment: No, it's only because  basic LaTeX forgets to swap the values of `\abovecaptionskip` (10pt by default, if I remember well) and `\belowcaptionskip` (0pt by default) when the caption is *above* table, whereas `caption` does.