# Label table without table environment

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx

I'd like to label a table without putting it into a table environment.
From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376118/labels-with-tabular#376121) I know that this wont work, but the solution offered there does not work either, because, if I put my table (tabularx) inside a table environment, the table does not continue on the next page but gives an overfull vbox error...
How do you solve such problems?
Thanks for any help!

This is the script I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, array}  

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
        @{}
        s{0.5}
        s{2}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}s{0.5}
        @{}
    }
\label{tab:primer}
    \caption[blabla]{blablabla}\\

    \toprule
    \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Sequence (5' $\rightarrow$ 3')} & \textbf{Application}\\[6pt]
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \toprule
    \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Sequence (5' $\rightarrow$ 3')} & \textbf{Application}\\[6pt]
    \midrule
    \endhead

    1 & 2 & 3\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (i) caption had not to be inside `tabularx` environment (ii) label had to be after `caption`, (iii) you can use `captionof{figure}{...}` for caption. For this you need to load the `caption` or the `capt-of` package.

Comment: please extend your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal Working Example: a small self contained document) which we can test. Missed are information about used packages in your document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons why your code fragment does not compile, even after adding the necessary document preamble:

1. You have a mix of [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/lontable) and [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) commands in your the table's preamble. The heading is for a `longtable`, but the column definitions are for a `tabularx`.
2. You have placed the `label` at wrong place. The best place is *inside* the caption, i.e. `\caption[blabla]{blablabla\label{tab:primer}}\\`.

If you are going to using [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), I suggest that you use a [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)-class and use the internal commands to set caption outside float, instead of the [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption)-package.

If you use [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/lontable), it has its own caption commands (and KOMA-script can blend in). However, you cannot use X-columns in a longtable without additional packages, for example [threeparttablex](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex) or [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular), as [Zarko suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505799/9632). I will add that [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) is a drop-in replacement for [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/lontable) and [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). You code will compile with three minor changes:

1. Replace [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) with [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) in your document's preamble
2. Move the `\label` inside the `caption` as described above. You should change `\\` to `\\[10pt]` at the end to have some space after the caption
3. Change `\begin{tabularx}` with `\begin{xltabular}` and `\end{tabularx}` with `\end{xltabular}`

Here is your example in a [scrartcl](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl)-class. This table will *not* break at page boundary. If you need that function, @Zarko has already given you a [workable solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505799/9632):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\captionaboveof{table}{blablabla%
     \label{tab:primer}%
     }

\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
        @{}
        s{0.5}
        s{2}
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}s{0.5}
        @{}
    }

    \toprule
    \textbf{Number} & \textbf{Sequence (5' $\rightarrow$ 3')} & \textbf{Application}\\[6pt]
    \midrule


    1 & 2 & 3\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was waiting on OP response, but you encourage me to publish my prepared answer :-). Anyway, OP's anyway, the document's preamble is still a mystery :-(. +1 for nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `xltabular`, a nice combination of the `longtable` and `tabularx`. It enable use of caption inside table environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\small}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{s}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}  c
                >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}R
                >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}R
                             @{} }
\caption[blabla]{blablabla}
\label{tab:primer}                  
\addtocounter{table}{-1}            \\
    \toprule
\thead{Number} 
    & \thead{Sequence ($5'\rightarrow 3'$)} 
        & \thead{Application}       \\ 
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{blablabla (cont.)}   \\
\thead{Number}
    & \thead{Sequence ($5'\rightarrow 3'$)}
        & \thead{Application}       \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace[-3pt]
\endhead
    \midrule[0.8pt]
\multicolumn{3}{r}{continue on the next page}     
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
 1  & 2 & 3                         \\
    \addlinespace
 2  & \lipsum[1-2]  &               \\
    \addlinespace
 3  & \lipsum[3]    &               \\
    \addlinespace
 4  & \lipsum[4]    &               \\
    \addlinespace
 5  & \lipsum[5]    &               \\
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And thank you for making me have a look at [xltabular](https://ctan.org/pkg/xltabular). The package is brilliant, direct drop-in for [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable).