# Caption and label on xltabular environment

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, labels, xltabular

I have been trying to add caption and label to a long table (not entirely written below) inside the `xltabular` environment.
After checking [Caption on tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31737/caption-on-tabular-environment), [labels with tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376118/labels-with-tabular) and some other posts, I did this:

```
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=-10pt}

\captionof{table}{My Table}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}Y|Y|Y@{}}
    0.0  & 0    & 0      \\
    1.0  & 1000 & 0      \\
    2.0  & 2000 & 0 
\end{xltabular}
```

which kinda works. However, I keep getting yellow warning messages:

`Package caption Warning: \captionsetup{type*=...} or \captionof outside box or environment on input line 161.`

`Package caption Warning: The option 'hypcap=true' will be ignored for this particular \caption on input line 161.`

Also, `\captionsetup[table]{skip=-10pt}` stops working if I use `\captionof{table}{My Table}` and I need it because the space between the table and the caption is too large.

How can I solve these problems without using `table` environment (it makes my table start in a new page)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As for longtable, the `\caption` command should be *inside* the `xltabular` environment. It is not a floating environmen, and it uses the same syntax as `longtable`..

Comment: I have tried that multiples times and it did not work. However, by being sure it should (due to your comment), I was able to do so by adding \\ after the caption. As for the label, I had to put it inside of `\caption{}`. It was just a matter or rearranging things after all, but I could only do it thanks to you... So, thanks, @Bernard! :)

Comment: BTW, @Bernard, won't I be able to use `\endhead`? Since it will repeat also the caption on every page, once it is inside the `xltabular` environment...

Comment: You can also use \endhead, \endfoot and \endlastfoot. No problem with that.

Comment: Yea, I know it works. However, it also repeats the caption on every page as if was a header, because it is right after `begin{xltabular}`, interpreted as a row. I wish I could specify which rows should be repeated.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to do this, check [How can I repeat the header but not the caption with longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71549/how-can-i-repeat-the-header-but-not-the-caption-with-longtable)

Comment: It is stated in the caption documentation that captionof does not work for longtable, see page 37 (section 6.8). If you want to setup special options for the longtable environment you can use `\captionsetup[longtable]{options}`. It should wotk for xltabular, too. Easier if you have more than one xltabular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic model for the use of the `xltabular` is the same as at `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2in, vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X|X|X @{}}
\caption{My Table}             % <---
\label{tab:mytab}   \\
    \hline
A   & B     & C     \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{My Table (cont)} \\ % <--- 
    \hline
A   & B     & C     \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
% table body
0.0 & 0     & 0     \\
1.0 & 1000  & 0     \\
2.0 & 2000  & 0     \\
3.0 & 3000  & 0     \\
4.0 & 4000  & 0     \\
5.0 & 5000  & 0     \\
6.0 & 6000  & 0     \\
7.0 & 7000  & 0     \\
\end{xltabular}
\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ashitaka, any news?

Comment: sorry for this late reply. I haven't checked this topic since my last message, which was prior to your answer. The solution given by Bernard on the comments solved my problem and it seems the only issue was the missing \\. Thank you for a complete answer!