# Obtaining the number of table in a reference

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, compiling

I have followed [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376118/labels-with-tabular) to label a table as

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
 \hline
  contents of the table \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab1:IFPositions}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

However, if I then write  `\ref{tab1:IFPositions}`, the resulting .pdf text returns ?? as the number of the reference, even if it redirects to the proper place. As far as I understand, this happens since there is no such thing as a table number, but I would like to know if there is a way for a table to be properly referenced instead of getting ?? as the number of reference.

Comment: The table counter is actually the number of table captions, not the number of table environments.  Throw in a `\refstepcounter{table}` if you don't want a `\caption`.

Comment: Add a \caption as shown in the answer. And don't put a center environment around a table, that is rather pointless.

Comment: Additionally `\begin{center}\begin{table} ... \end{table}\end{center}` makes no sense. Use `\begin{table}[htp] \centering ... \end{table}` instead. Note that I added `[htp]` to `\begin{table}` you can also use `[htbp]` the default value in most classes are `[tbp]`